# Reshape dataframe to dataframe with unlimited rows and filling zeroes where no values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, reshape

Is there a way to reshape DataFrame to another with unrestricted rows. I just want a DataFrame with 3 columns, no matter how many rows is going to be in DataFrame?

For example,

```
letters = pd.DataFrame({'Letters' : ['A', 'B', 'C','D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 
'I','J']})

Letters
0   A
1   B
2   C
3   D
4   E
5   F
6   G
7   H
8   I
9   J
```

and I want to reshape it like this with filling zeroes, where there is no value.

```
first   second  third
A       B       C
D       E       F
G       H       I
J       0       0
```

In numpy reshape method as far as I know you need to explicitly identify, how much columns and rows you want..

Comment: So you want to spread it over three columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(letters.groupby(letters.index // 3)['Letters']
                          .apply(list)
                          .values
                          .tolist(), columns=['first','second','third']).fillna(0))

print (df)
  first second third
0     A      B     C
1     D      E     F
2     G      H     I
3     J      0     0
```

Comment: Thank you vry much!

Answer (score 6):

You could use [NumPy reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html). `arr.reshape((-1, 3))` tells NumPy to reshape `arr` to shape `(n, 3)` where `n` is computed for you based on the size of `arr` and the size of the other given dimension(s) (e.g. in this example, the value 3).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

letters = pd.DataFrame({'Letters' : ['A', 'B', 'C','D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I','J']})
arr = np.empty(((len(letters) - 1)//3 + 1)*3, dtype='O')
arr[:len(letters)] = letters['Letters']
result = pd.DataFrame(arr.reshape((-1, 3)), columns='first second third'.split())
result = result.fillna(0)
print(result)
```

prints

```
  first second third
0     A      B     C
1     D      E     F
2     G      H     I
3     J      0     0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really simple solution, I haven't expect