# Rearanging table structure based on number of rows and columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame table. The table has the columns Id, columns, rows, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9.

```
Id  columns rows  1  2  3  4  5   6  7  8  9 
1     3      3    A  B  C  D  E   F  G  H  Z
2     3      2    I  J  K
```

By considering Id, the number of rows, and columns I would like to restructure the table as follows.

```
Id columns rows col_1  col_2  col_3
1    3      3    A       B      C
1    3      3    D       E      F
1    3      3    G       H      Z

2    3      2    I       J      K
2    3      2    -       -      -
```

Can anyone help to do this in Python Pandas?

Comment: Why is it there is just one empty row in `Id==2`? Do you really need it there?

Comment: Can you please explain how the transformation should take place?

Comment: @QuangHoang Because as you see the ```rows``` column it has two (2) rows but the first has a value but the second row is empty. and you can ignore the rest since the row value is 2.

Comment: @methk The transformation is based on the number of rows and columns. Mainly depend of the number of rows. Depending the number of rows start new row when you have with that specific number of columns.

Comment: Ah, but then do the columns always stay the same as `3`?

Comment: @QuangHoang for this example is the same. But it might be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) and [`.itterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```
df
```

```
   Id  columns  rows  1  2  3     4     5     6     7     8     9
0   1        3     3  A  B  C     D     E     F     G     H     Z
1   2        3     2  I  J  K  None  None  None  None  None  None
```

You can set `n` to any length, in your case 3:

```py
n = 3

df = df.set_index(['Id', 'columns', 'rows'])

new_index = []
new_rows = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    max_rows = index[-1] * (len(index)-1)  # read amount of rows
    for i in range(0, len(row), n):
        if i > max_rows:  # max rows reached, stop appending
            continue
        new_index.append(index)
        new_rows.append(row.values[i:i+n])

pd.DataFrame(new_rows, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_index))
```

```
          0     1     2
1 3 3     A     B     C
    3     D     E     F
    3     G     H     Z
2 3 2     I     J     K
    2  None  None  None
```

And if you are keen on getting your old index and headers back:

```py
new_headers = ['Id', 'columns', 'rows'] + list(range(1, n+1))
df2.reset_index().set_axis(new_headers, axis=1)
```

```
   Id  columns  rows     1     2     3
0   1        3     3     A     B     C
1   1        3     3     D     E     F
2   1        3     3     G     H     Z
3   2        3     2     I     J     K
4   2        3     2  None  None  None
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer this.  For the ```Id = 1``` it is correct, it has 3 rows and 3 columns. But for ```Id =2``` is that possible to make the number of rows only 2 instead of 3 since  the number of ```rows =2```

Comment: Yes that is possible. I have edited the for loop in the answer (commented rows).

Answer (score 0):

Using `melt` and `str.split` with floor division against your index to create groups of 3.

```
s = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Id','columns','rows'])


s1 = (
    s.sort_values(["Id", "variable"])
    .assign(idx=s.index // 3)
    .fillna("-")
    .groupby(["idx", "Id"])
    .agg(
        columns=("columns", "first"), rows=("rows", "first"), value=("value", ",".join)
    )
)

s2 = s1["value"].str.split(",", expand=True).rename(

        columns=dict(zip(s1["value"].str.split(",", expand=True).columns,
        [f'col_{i+1}' for i in range(s1["value"].str.split(',').apply(len).max())]
    ))
)


df1 = pd.concat([s1.drop('value',axis=1),s2],axis=1)

print(df1)

        columns  rows col_1 col_2 col_3
idx Id                                 
0   1         3     3     A     B     C
1   1         3     3     D     E     F
2   1         3     3     G     H     Z
3   2         3     2     I     J     K
4   2         3     2     -     -     -
5   2         3     2     -     -     -
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One question: Did you consider the number of rows and columns?

Comment: Only columns, the rows are calculated by the delta of values within rows 1-9 @Kapital

Comment: Sorry for very late reply. I just came back to this. Is that possible to consider only rows and Id. Let us assume the ```column``` is fixed.

Comment: please create a [mcve] and I'll change my answer @Kapital

Answer (score 0):

I modify [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48630234/2901002) solution for create array for each row by expected length of new rows, columns, then create Dataframe in list comprehension and join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
def f(x):
    c, r = x.name[1], x.name[2]
    #print (c, r)
    arr = np.empty(c * r, dtype='O')
    vals = x.iloc[:len(arr)]
    arr[:len(vals)] = vals
    idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([x.name] * r, names=df.columns[:3])
    cols = [f'col_{c+1}' for c in range(c)]
    return pd.DataFrame(arr.reshape((r, c)), index=idx, columns=cols).fillna('-')


df1 = (pd.concat([x for x in df.set_index(['Id', 'columns', 'rows'])
         .apply(f, axis=1)])
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
   Id  columns  rows col_1 col_2 col_3
0   1        3     3     A     B     C
1   1        3     3     D     E     F
2   1        3     3     G     H     Z
3   2        3     2     I     J     K
4   2        3     2     -     -     -
```